# The method '[]' was called on null in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to get the data returned from a method 'getData()' into a List 'datat' but i am getting this error 
:  ' The method '[]' was called on null '
this is the corresponding code  :

```
ListeMedecinsState() {
    /* Fetching Data Into ListView */

    Future<String> getData() async {
      var response = await http.get(
          Uri.encodeFull("http://10.0.2.2:4000/user/GetAllMedecins"),
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json"
          }
      );

      this.setState(() {

        this.data = json.decode(response.body);
      });


      return "Success";
    }

    getData()  ;
    print(this.data[1]["email"]);

    /* Fetching Data Into ListView */
  }
```

Notice : when i retreive the data into the list inside the method it shows no error, i want to use the data outside of the method scope how can i do please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, you could do it this way:

```
getData().then((data){
    //do something with data
});
```

Comment: just so you know... that's the same thing as await / async.. just a different syntax.  @Pedro is completely correct. The problem you were having, yassine is where you put your "async" (the second one) it should be on the function.

Answer (score 1):

You should **`await`** `getData();`

But please post your full code so it's more understandable.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry for that @Sebastian , please have a look on the code now and tell me if there is something else missing , thank you .

Comment: I believe @Sebastian is correct.  Did you try running the code with the second to last line reading "await getData()" ?

Comment: @WilliamTerrill you mean i should remove the async ?

Answer (score 1):

@Sebastian is correct. (so select his answer not mine. I'm only posting here so that you can see the complete code) Your code should read:

```
ListeMedecinsState() async {  // <-- this has to be added as well 
    /* Fetching Data Into ListView */

    Future<String> getData() async {
      var response = await http.get(
          Uri.encodeFull("http://10.0.2.2:4000/user/GetAllMedecins"),
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json"
          }
      );

      this.setState(() {

        this.data = json.decode(response.body);
      });


      return "Success";
    }

    await getData()  ;  // <--- your code needs to pause until the Future returns.
    print(this.data[1]["email"]);

    /* Fetching Data Into ListView */   }
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer @William i just tested your code i had to use that expression 'await getData()' i had to add async modifier to 'ListeMedecinsState()' like that  '  _ListeMedecinsState() async' then i got an error because of that which is 'error: The modifier 'async' can't be applied to the body of a constructor'

Answer (score 0):

As Sebastian said, your ListeMedecinState should be asynchronous. 
So that you can await the request and only proceed on it completion.

Your code actually doesn't wait for the result of getData() method before proceeding.
So you should **await** it before trying to access the data fetched !

Hope this helps !

(Seems like you speak French, I speak French too just in case you get lost) :)

Comment: Bonjour Sebastien , j'ai suivi le code comme @William l'a publier , j' du ajouter async modifier comme ca '_ListeMedecinsState() async' mais j'ai eu cet erreur :The modifier 'async' can't be applied to the body of a constructor.

Comment: Ce n'est pas moi Sebastian. Qu'est ce que c'est que ListeMedecinsState, où est-ce que tu l'utilise et qu'est ce qu'il fait ?
Essai de changer ListeMedecinsState en une méthode, où est-ce moi qui ne comprends pas le contexte dans lequel est utilisé ListeMedecins

Comment: Desolé  @Espera Awo , c'est resolu merci bien pour votre aide  .

Comment: Je t'en prie Yassine.